# Sequelize doesn't read the new modelname after I do refactor (remove s in end modelname)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've a backend app built in **Express** with **Sequelize ORM**. 
Here is my code;

user.js (model)

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const user = sequelize.define('user', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,        
  }, {
    // tableName: 'user'
  });
    user.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return user;
};
```

user.js (controller):

```
const User = require('../models').user;
module.exports = {
    getUser: function (req, res) {
        User.findAll().then(value => {
            res.json(value);
        })
    }    
}
```

When I start the project, it return error `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "users" does not exist`. As you can see my code above, I've set the model as `user` not `users`, and the table in db also **user** not **users**. It's only work fine if I add the `tableName: 'user'` in the model file.

> NOTE: By the default, when I do create model with sequelize, the file name and model define is `users`, but I refactor file name and define inside model into `user`

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [default behavior](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html#configuration) - `Sequelize` automatically transforms model name to plural. In order to disable that you should freeze table name in model definition (or just set table name explicitly like you are actually doing):

```
freezeTableName: true,
```